# WSO2 API Manager doesn't respond correctly to the APIs

Tags: api, wso2

I've got installed the manager, and put it on some APIs, the problem comes when I try to make a call to the API and the result is always the same. It shows:

https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp

I really don't know why is that.

Version: WSO2 API Manager 2.2.0

Comment: how do you call the api? is the api working from the api store?

Comment: I'm using curl. The api is working correctly, the problems comes when need to pass thru my server. Then I get the default response of .../carbon/admin/login.jsp

Comment: the logon screen is redirected if the request goes to the admin port (9443) and unknown resource. The API is exposed on the nio port 8243 (or 8280) by default. If the api is callable from the store, aren't you using the same endpoint as displayed in the store?

Answer (score 0):

Try following the **Invoking the API** section of the below document. If you are going to try with CURL, this will show the CURL request format too.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-InvokingtheAPI

Comment: I'm doing that, but the result is default webpage and the curl request is not redirected to the API.

Comment: It would be easy to identify the issue by looking at the HTTP headers and messages passed from the logs. Please follow the steps below to enable these logs.

Go to the <API-M_HOME>/repository/conf directory and open the log4j.properties.
Edit the entries for the two loggers as follows by removing the commented (#).
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG 

Restart the server and please share the relevant logs from <API-M_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log for an API call which get the issue.

Comment: Finally I decide to upgrade to the version 2.5.0 and finally the apis works correctly, the only issue I've got now is when I request the curl, shows:               TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.  But when I copy the result of the CURL command and execute it on the console of the server, the request data shows correctly. So my question is how I can resolve the issue.